# Passing text value Lightning Component Controller to Apex Class?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-experience, lightning-design-system

I have a quick action button in feed and it is related to lead object.
Picklist value called "External user" . While selecting the value the "Email" field is enabled. Take the email value and pass the value to controller.

Lightning Component:

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,force:lightningQuickActionWithoutHeader" access="global" controller="LeadEmailOutIntegratorSS">
  <aura:attribute name="leadId" type="String" default="NotDefined" />
  <aura:attribute name="recordId" type="String" default="NotDefined" />
  <aura:attribute name="selectedText" type="string" />
  <aura:attribute name="myText" type="string" />
  <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />
  <div class="c-container">
    <lightning:card>
      <aura:set attribute="title">
        Send Lead To External
      </aura:set>
      <lightning:layout verticalAlign="end" horizontalAlign="space">
        <lightning:layoutItem flexibility="grow" padding="around-small">
          <ui:inputSelect aura:id="ExternalSystemSelector" multiple="false" value="{!v.selectedText}">
            <ui:inputSelectOption text="ATURB" label="ATURB" value="true" />
            <ui:inputSelectOption text="Lead Central" label="Lead Central" />
            <ui:inputSelectOption text="Baldor" label="Baldor" />
            <ui:inputSelectOption text="External User" label="External User" />
          </ui:inputSelect>
        </lightning:layoutItem>
        <lightning:layoutItem flexibility="shrink" padding="around-small">
          <aura:if isTrue="{!v.selectedText == 'External User' ? 'true' : 'false'  }">
            <ui:inputText aura:id="ExternalUserEmailId" label="Email" class="field" value="{!v.myText}" />
          </aura:if>
        </lightning:layoutItem>
        <lightning:layoutItem flexibility="shrink" padding="around-small">
          <lightning:button variant="brand" label="Send" onclick="{!c.sendToExternalSystem}" />
        </lightning:layoutItem>
      </lightning:layout>
    </lightning:card>
  </div>
</aura:component>
```

Lightning Controller:

```
({
  doInit: function(cmp, event, helper) {
    var leadId = cmp.get("v.leadId");
    //alert('test ' + leadId);
    var recordId = cmp.get("v.recordId");
    //alert('recordId ' + recordId);
    if (leadId.indexOf('[') != -1) {
      leadId = leadId.substring(1, leadId.length - 1)
      //alert('test ' + leadId);
      var newleadId = leadId.split(', ');
      //alert('test ' + newleadId);
      cmp.set("v.leadId", newleadId);
    }
    if (leadId === 'NotDefined') {
      leadId = [recordId];
      cmp.set("v.leadId", leadId);
    };
    var leadId = cmp.get("v.leadId");
    //alert('newLeadId ' +leadId);
  },
  sendToExternalSystem: function(component, event, helper) {
    var leadIds = component.get("v.leadId");
    //alert('sendToExternalSystem ' + leadIds); 
    //alert('isArray ' + Array.isArray(leadId)); 
    //alert('isArray ' + Array.isArray(leadId);
    var selectCmp = component.find("ExternalSystemSelector");
    var theExternalSystemName = selectCmp.get("v.value"); ** // Passing the aura:id to here
    var ExtUser = component.find("ExternalUserEmailId");
    var theExtUserEmail = selectCmp.get("v.value"); **

    //alert('theExternalSystemName ' + theExternalSystemName);        
    var action = component.get("c.sendLeadToExternalSystem");
    //var action = component.get("c.sendLeadToTechnicalContacts")
    **
    action.setParams({
      externalSystem: theExternalSystemName,
      leadIds: leadIds,
      extUserEmailId: theExtUserEmail
    }); // here setting the parameters**
    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {


    });
    var btn = event.getSource();
    btn.set("v.disabled", true); //Disable the button   
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
  }
})
```

Apex Class:

```
@AuraEnabled
public static void sendLeadToExternalSystem(String externalSystem, List < Id > leadIds, String extUserEmailId) {
    System.debug('externalSystem :' + externalSystem);
    System.debug('leadIds :' + leadIds);
    System.debug('leadIds.size() :' + leadIds.size());
    System.debug('extUserEmailId :' + extUserEmailId);

    List < Lead > leads = [
        SELECT Id, FirstName, LastName, Name, Email, Phone, Company, City, State, PostalCode, Country, RefererUrl__c, Description__c
        FROM Lead
        WHERE ID in: leadIds Limit 50000
    ];



    Map < String, Id > technicalcontact;
    List < Contact > conList;
    conList = [select id, name, email from contact where Account.name = 'Technical Account'
        and Email != null AND(name = 'ATURB'
            or Name = 'Lead Central'
            or Name = 'Baldor'
            or Email =: extUserEmailId) limit 50000
    ];
    account accquery = new Account();
    accQuery = [Select id from account where name = 'Technical Account'
        limit 1
    ];
    System.debug('conList : ' + conList);
    technicalcontact = new Map < String, Id > ();
    Contact con;
    //technicalcontact= new Map<String,Id>();
    for (contact ct: conlist) {
        if (ct.name.equalsIgnorecase('Lead Central')) {
            technicalcontact.put('Lead Central', ct.id);
            System.debug('******************' + technicalcontact);
        }
        if (ct.name.equalsIgnorecase('ATURB')) {
            technicalcontact.put('ATURB', ct.id);
        }
        if (ct.name.equalsIgnorecase('Baldor')) {
            technicalcontact.put('Baldor', ct.id);
        }

        if (externalSystem.equals('External User') && extUserEmailId != NULL && externalSystem != NULL && extUserEmailId.equals(ct.email)) {
            technicalcontact.put('External User', ct.id);
        } else {
            con = new Contact();
            con.LastName = 'Technical Contact';
            con.Email = extUserEmailId;
            con.accountId = accquery.id;

        }
    }

    if (con != NULL) {
        insert con;
        System.debug('con:' + con);
        technicalcontact.put('External User', con.id);
    }

    System.debug('technicalcontact : ' + technicalcontact);
    Id owaId = null;
    EmailServices.Template theTemplate = EmailServices.prepareTemplate('Lead_To_External_System_Template');
    //Id externalSystemId = externalSystem2Id.get( externalSystem );
    id externalSystemId = technicalcontact.get(externalSystem);
    List < Messaging.SingleEmailMessage > emails = new List < Messaging.SingleEmailMessage > ();
    List < EmailMessage > emailMessages = new List < EmailMessage > ();
    List < EmailWrapper > emailWrappers = new List < EmailWrapper > ();
    List < Task > tasks = new List < Task > ();
    String unqualifiedReason = externalSystem2UnqualifiedReason.get(externalSystem);
    for (Lead theLead: leads) {
        Map < String, String > placeholderName2Value = prepareMergeFields(theLead);
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage theEmail = theTemplate.renderSingleEmail(placeholderName2Value);
        theEmail.setTargetObjectId(externalSystemId);
        theEmail.setSaveAsActivity(false);
        emails.add(theEmail);
        theLead.Status = 'Unqualified';
        theLead.Unqualifying_Reason__c = unqualifiedReason;
        EmailMessage theEmailMessage = new EmailMessage(
            HtmlBody = theEmail.getHtmlBody(),
            Subject = theEmail.getSubject(),
            //ActivityId = '00T7E000008HF2m'
            Status = '3',
            LeadId__c = thelead.id

            //FromAddress = 'from@xxx.xxx',
            //ToAddress = 'to@xxx.xxx'                
        );
        //theEmailMessage.ToIds = new List<Id>{theLead.Id};
        emailMessages.add(theEmailMessage);
        //EmailMessageRelation theEmailMessageRelation = new EmailMessageRelation(
        Task theTask = new Task(
            whoId = theLead.Id,
            Description = theEmail.getHtmlBody(),
            Subject = theEmail.getSubject(),
            TaskSubtype = 'Email'
        );

        tasks.add(theTask);
        EmailWrapper theEmailWrapper = new EmailWrapper(
            theLead,
            theEmailMessage,
            theTask
        );
        emailWrappers.add(theEmailWrapper);

    }
    Messaging.sendEmail(emails);
    update leads;


    List < EmailMessageRelation > emailRelations = new List < EmailMessageRelation > ();


    for (EmailWrapper theEmailWrapper: emailWrappers) {
        /* EmailMessageRelation theEmailRelation = new EmailMessageRelation(
             EmailMessageId = theEmailWrapper.emailMember.Id,
             RelationId = theEmailWrapper.leadMember.Id,
             RelationType = 'fromAddress'
         );*/
        theEmailWrapper.taskMember.whoId = theEmailWrapper.leadMember.Id;
        //theEmailWrapper.taskMember.whatId = theEmailWrapper.emailMember.Id;
        // emailRelations.add( theEmailRelation );
    }
    insert tasks;
    insert emailMessages;
    for (EmailWrapper theEmailWrapper: emailWrappers) {
        EmailMessageRelation theEmailRelationTo = new EmailMessageRelation(
            EmailMessageId = theEmailWrapper.emailMember.Id,
            RelationId = externalSystemId,
            RelationType = 'toAddress'
        );
        //theEmailWrapper.emailMember.RelatedToId = theEmailWrapper.taskMember.Id;
        emailRelations.add(theEmailRelationTo);
        EmailMessageRelation theEmailRelationFrom = new EmailMessageRelation(
            EmailMessageId = theEmailWrapper.emailMember.Id,
            RelationId = UserInfo.getUserId(),
            RelationType = 'fromAddress'
        );
        emailRelations.add(theEmailRelationFrom);
    }
    insert emailRelations;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have problem in your **sendToExternalSystem** method. The way you are trying to get selected value from "ExternalSystemSelector" picklist and email entered in "" input text is incorrect.

Some correction needs in **sendToExternalSystem** in Component's controller.js

```
    sendToExternalSystem: function(component, event, helper) {
        var leadIds = component.get("v.leadId");
        // We have selectedText attribute binded to picklist
        // So user selected value will be stored in it. 
        // Here get selected value from selectedText attribute.
        var theExternalSystemName = component.get("v.selectedText");

        // Similar to picklist we have myText attribute binded to input text
        // So user selected value will be stored in it. 
        // Here get selected value from myText attribute.
        var theExtUserEmail = component.get("v.myText");

        console.log('1. theExternalSystemName ' + theExternalSystemName);
        console.log('2. theExtUserEmail ' + theExtUserEmail);   
        var action = component.get("c.sendLeadToExternalSystem");
        action.setParams({
            externalSystem: theExternalSystemName,
            leadIds: leadIds,
            extUserEmailId: theExtUserEmail
        }); 
        action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        });
        var btn = event.getSource();
        btn.set("v.disabled", true); //Disable the button   
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }
```

As User selected and entered values are getting stored in aura:attribute, you can easily get them in your controller.js as:

```
var theExternalSystemName = component.get("v.selectedText");
var theExtUserEmail = component.get("v.myText");
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. But I have One more thing i was struggleing.

Comment: And what is that ?

Comment: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/189223/if-else-is-not-working

Comment: Please see the link